# Como manter as cores de itens que tiveram as cores alteradas do listView no Android?

Tags: android

Eu tenho um listView, e quando clico em um item da lista ele muda de cor, eu precisava manter esta cor mesmo depois que a activity da lista fosse chamada de novo. É possível fazer isso sem precisar gravar a cor no banco? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: dê uma olhada se pode lhe ajudar em algo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click

Comment: isso é outra coisa, eu precisava só salvar as cores dos itens, por exemplo em uma lista com 20 países, se eu clicar no 2º país, o item dele vai ficar verde, os outros continuarão brancos, eu precisava manter esse verde esse verde mesmo depois que a activity da lista for chamada novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Extenda a classe Application do android,e tenha um ArrayList static dentro do seu application para salvar essas cores, salve cor e posição do item na lista do ArrayList.

Detalhe essa informação só irá ficar salva até que o aplicativo seja fechado. Caso feche e abra novamente irá vir com as informações padrão, para conseguir persistir esses dados permanentemente, apenas com banco de dados.